# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when Translating

Tags: java, localization, apertium

I am using the Apertium Translator and using the sample code they provide. My code is like this.

```
import com.robtheis.aptr.language.Language;
import com.robtheis.aptr.translate.Translate;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Set the Apertium API Key - Get yours at http://api.apertium.org/register.jsp
    Translate.setKey("BNSCFhEL8DoTApc2I1+aa3UYkVg");

    String translatedText = Translate.execute("Hola, mundo!", Language.SPANISH, Language.ENGLISH);

    System.out.println(translatedText);
}
}
```

I have no errors or warnings and when I run the program I get the following errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/JSONValue
at com.robtheis.aptr.ApertiumTranslatorAPI.jsonSubObjToString(ApertiumTranslatorAPI.java:195)
at com.robtheis.aptr.ApertiumTranslatorAPI.retrieveSubObjString(ApertiumTranslatorAPI.java:140)
at com.robtheis.aptr.translate.Translate.execute(Translate.java:56)
at maple.Test.main(Test.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.JSONValue
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 4 more
```

The .jar I'm using is the second one from https://github.com/rmtheis/apertium-translator-java-api/downloads

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to download the first one. The first jar file (**apertium-translator-java-api-0.2-jar-with-dependencies.jar**) contains the all dependencies needed..

Or you add a json library to your project path..

Comment: Using the first download also produces the same error. How do I add the json library to my project path?

Comment: Okay.. Download this json lib https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/detail?name=json-simple-1.1.1.jar&can=2&q= and add it to your build path.. it should work. The apertium translotar uses this library but it is not added as dependency.. Thats why you get the NoClassDefFoundError..

Comment: When I do that the import and the Translate.xxx provides me with errors.

Comment: Thank you, I was removing the old one thinking that the dependency was the only one I was supposed to add.

Answer (score 0):

Well JVM is not able to find some class at Runtime which was available at compile time. That is the reason of **NoClassDefFoundError** 
Below you also have **ClassNotFoundException** for this class ***org.json.simple.JSONValue***
which means you are trying to load the particular class at run-time by name.
Both of them related to **Java Class Path**. 
I don't know alot about jSON stuff. But you are missing this file org.json.simple.JSONValue you can take it from here http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
add the above jar file in your class path . And the code will definitely run. Guaranteed.!!!

 Thanks